# Insert sample records using Apex

Tags: apex, create-records

I would like to insert a bunch of sample account records (50 or so), without using the data loader. I have written code, but I do not know how to proceed. Where can I run it?

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>{'fast', 'lunar', 'modern', 'super', 'retro', 'traditional'};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>{'car', 'cat', 'mining', 'office', 'computer', 'ship'};
List<Account> accountsList = new List<account>();

for (String first: firstList){
    for(string second: secondList) {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = first + ' ' + second + ' co';
           accountsList.add(a);
    }
}

insert accountsList;
```

Comment: `List<string> firstList = new List<string>{'fast', 'lunar', 'modern', 'super', 'retro', 'traditional'};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>{'car', 'cat', 'mining', 'office', 'computer', 'ship'};
List<Account> accountsList = new List<account>();
    
for (String first: firstList){
    for(string second: secondList) {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = first + ' ' + second + ' co';
        a.code__c = 'abc';
     accountsList.add(a);
    }    
}

insert accountsList;    `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will use the developer console to insert your apex.

To find the developer console, go to name-> *Developer Console*:

[image]

Once you are in the developer console, click on menu *Debug* -> *Open Execute Anonymous Windows*:

[image]

I see you are new to Apex and coding so get on to the [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/) and get some training.

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_database/apex_database_intro

Comment: thanks, i was able to insert the records, after correcting the bug in my code.

Comment: @user3520799 mark as answered so that others can find easily

Comment: In the screenshot, menu command "Developer Console" appears to be in menu "mohit srivastav", not menu "Setup". What is correct?

Comment: @peter great observation .just corrected!!